# PHPWord - problem with styles in tag "<ol>"

Tags: php, css, ms-word, phpword

Below is a source code snippet that works. The problem comes when I try to modify the '' tag styles. The color works, but the text refuses to justify itself and the spacing between elements won't change to 0 pt.

```
<?php 
    use PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord;
    use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html;
    require "../vendor/autoload.php";
    require("../config.php");
    require("../auth.php");
    
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `mp_umowy` WHERE IdUmowy = $id;";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die ( mysqli_error($con) );
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    
    $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
    $section = $phpWord->addSection(
    array('marginLeft' => 1000, 'marginRight' => 1000,
    'marginTop' => 1000, 'marginBottom' => 1000)
    );

    $html = 
    '
    <p style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 0pkt;"><strong>§ 2</strong></p>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Wynagrodzenie</strong></p>
    <ol style="text-align:justify; margin-bottom: 0pkt; padding-bottom: 0pkt;">
        <li style="text-align:justify; margin-bottom: 0pkt;"><p style="text-align:justify; margin-bottom: 0pkt;">Strony ustalają, że zgodnie z obowiązującym cennikiem koszt wynajmu, o którym mowa w § 1 wyniesie <strong> '.$row['kwota'].' zł brutto</strong> (słownie: '.$row['kwota_slownie'].').</p></li>
        <li style="text-align:justify; margin-bottom: 0pkt; color:red;"><p style="text-align:justify; margin-bottom: 0pkt;">Płatność z tytułu niniejszej umowy zostanie uregulowana przez Najemcę po zakończeniu wynajmu i otrzymaniu faktury VAT od Wynajmującego.</p></li>
    </ol>
    ';


    \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $html, false, false);
    $phpWord->setDefaultFontSize(11);
    $phpWord->setDefaultFontName('Times New Roman');
    $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
    $plik = str_replace('/', '-', $row['numer']);
    $objWriter->save("../umowy/Umowa_nr_$plik.docx");
    header("Location: wynajem_view.php?id=$id");
    
?>
```

I don't know where is the problem. In the "p" tag everything works as it should. What can I do to fix it? A similar problem occurs with the "" tag.

Comment: `0pkt` is not the same as `0pt`. Though you can just use `0` instead

Comment: I tried it. It doesn't work. But still text-align:justify dosen't work. But it should, in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer on Github, this works fine for me. https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/2304.

In /PhpWord/Shared/Html.php, you modify function `parseListItem`

```
protected static function parseListItem($node, $element, &$styles, $data)
    {
        $cNodes = $node->childNodes;
        if (!empty($cNodes)) {
            
             /*FIX issue with incorrect style parsing  of LI element*/
             $styles['paragraph'] = self::recursiveParseStylesInHierarchy($node, $styles['paragraph']);
            /**/

            $listRun = $element->addListItemRun($data['listdepth'], $styles['list'], $styles['paragraph']);
            foreach ($cNodes as $cNode) {
                self::parseNode($cNode, $listRun, $styles, $data);
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps you